# listop operator causing infinite recursion, any way to fix?

Tags: raku

I'm looking to possibly help update the [File::HomeDir](https://github.com/azawawi/perl6-file-homedir) module which was never finished. While inspecting it, I noticed that stubbed out methods were causing infinite loops:

In the `File::HomeDir` role:

```
unit class File::HomeDir;

use File::HomeDir::Win32;
use File::HomeDir::MacOSX;
use File::HomeDir::Unix;

my File::HomeDir $singleton;

method new
{
  return $singleton if $singleton.defined;
  
  if $*DISTRO.is-win {
    $singleton = self.bless does File::HomeDir::Win32;
  } elsif $*DISTRO.name.starts-with('macos') {
    $singleton = self.bless does File::HomeDir::MacOSX;
  } else {
    $singleton = self.bless does File::HomeDir::Unix;
  }

  return $singleton;
}

method my-home {
  return File::HomeDir.new.my-home;
}

method my-desktop {
  return File::HomeDir.new.my-desktop;
}

<snip>
```

In the `File::HomeDir::MacOSX` module:

```
use v6;

unit role File::HomeDir::MacOSX;

method my-home {
  # Try HOME on every platform first, because even on Windows, some
  # unix-style utilities rely on the ability to overload HOME.
  return %*ENV<HOME> if %*ENV<HOME>.defined;
  return;
}

method my-desktop {
  !!!
}

<snip>
```

With this code, calling `say File::HomeDir.my-desktop;` results in an infinite loop.

This module was first written about 5 1/2 years ago. I'm assuming it worked at the time. But it appears now that if a role method has a listop operator, it causes the parent's class to be called which then called the role method which then calls the parent class, etc.

Comment: I'd assume that if this problem has existed for 5+ years and nobody noticed it or fixed it, that this distribution is not in use.  And thus its API could not be considered stable.  And thus you're free to take it anywhere you want.

Comment: The developer is still around and active and I play on reaching out to them. But that's kind of a separate issue. I am curious as to how this particular issue might be addressed (and why it might have worked in the past but does not now).

Comment: Actually, looking a little deeper I wonder why there would be any blessing needed if there's a singleton involved.  Looks like $singleton only needs the appropriate role mixed in.

Comment: Thanks. How do I mix in the appropriate role to the $singleton?

Comment: Maybe https://docs.raku.org/routine/add_role?

Comment: `$singleton = File::HomeDir but File::HomeDir::Unix;`  https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_but

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know about that operator. But I'm still getting an infinite loop.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/lizmat/e30c6866ba3a886dcfd5956ed62caf6f for how I would do it

Comment: That works. But if I replace the `dd`s with a listop like `!!!` I just get an infinite loop. Maybe the original module relied on a broken implementation and now that things are fixed the proper behavior is an infinite loop?

Comment: That's weird: I get `Method 'my-home' must be implemented by File::HomeDir::MacOSX because it is required by roles: File::HomeDir::MacOSX.`

Comment: Huh. What version of rakudo?

Comment: HEAD  aka v2022.07-39-g29eadbb29

Comment: OK, I just installed HEAD (v2022.07-41-g90709d533) on a docker image and I now see what you see. I wonder what changed between 2022.07 and HEAD?

Comment: Now I'm really confused. Running your github gist code, modified with listops, on 2022.07 (non HEAD) on mac results in infinite loop while 2022.07 (non HEAD) on a debian docker image does not.

Comment: I must have inadvertently changed your code. I copied and pasted it again and now things are working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it like this, staying close to the original design:

```
role File::HomeDir::Win32 {
    method my-home()    { dd }
    method my-desktop() { dd }
}

role File::HomeDir::MacOSX {
    method my-home()    { dd }
    method my-desktop() { dd }
}

role File::HomeDir::Unix {
    method my-home()    { dd }
    method my-desktop() { dd }
}

class File::HomeDir {

    my $singleton;
    # Return singleton, make one if there isn't one already
    sub singleton() {
        without $singleton {
            $_ = File::HomeDir but $*DISTRO.is-win
              ?? File::HomeDir::Win32
              !! $*DISTRO.name.starts-with('macos')
                ?? File::HomeDir::MacOSX
                !! File::HomeDir::Unix;
        }
        $singleton
    }

    method my-home()    { singleton.my-home }
    method my-desktop() { singleton.my-desktop }
}

File::HomeDir.my-home;
File::HomeDir.my-desktop;
```